Unable to find a suitable ansatz for finding the particular solution to a nonhomogeneous problem
I want to find the general solution of the system:
$$
x'(t) = A x(t) + g(t)
$$
where
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} -3 & 1 \\ -1 & -5 \end{bmatrix}, 
\quad g(t) = \begin{bmatrix} e^{-4t} \\ 2 \end{bmatrix} 
$$
It seems like the method of undetermined coefficients would be best here.
I first found the homogeneous solution:
$$
x(t) = c_1\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} e^{-4t} + c_2 \left(\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}te^{-4t}+\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}e^{-4t}\right) 
$$
Now I find the particular solution:
$$
x_p = \begin{bmatrix} Ae^{-4t} \\ Be^{-4t} + C \end{bmatrix} 
$$
subbing into the equation and solving, I get the following system of equations:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
-4A &= -3A+B+1 \\
-4B &= -A-5B
\end{aligned}
\right. 
\quad \implies \quad 
\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
-A &= B+1 \\
-4B &= -A-5B
\end{aligned}
\right. 
$$
Sub first eq into second: $-4B=B+1-5B \implies 0=1??$
I assume this means my ansatz is wrong, so I tried with a few different forms and haven't figured out something that works.
My questions are:

Is the method of undetermined coefficients best for this problem?
How do I know what form the ansatz should be?

Thank you for your help.

Undetermined coefficients works fine, but you should look at the two exponents $-4$ and $0$ separately.  Since $-4$ is a double root of the characteristic polynomial (an eigenvalue of $A$ of algebraic multiplicity $2$), you should look at a particular solution for $$x' = A x + e^{-4t} \pmatrix{1 \cr 0\cr}$$ of the form $$x = e^{-4t} \pmatrix{a_2 t^2 + a_1 t + a_0 \cr b_2 t^2 + b_1 t + b_0\cr}$$
And since $0$ is not a root, you should look for a constant solution of $$x' = A x + \pmatrix{0\cr 2\cr}$$
